# Fatou's Lemma applied to simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that the sequence of measurable functions $f_i: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

defined via \begin{align*}f_i(x)=
    \begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      -1 & i \leq x \leq i+1 \\
     0 & o.w. \\
    \end{array}
\end{array} 
\end{align*} (o.w. stands for otherwise of course) satisfies

lim inf $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_i < \int_{\mathbb{R}}$ lim inf $f_i$

So I am approaching this using Fatou's Lemma. In order to apply Fatou's Lemma however I define

\begin{align*}
g_i(x):=-f_i(x)
\end{align*} to ensure nonnegtivity. To invoke Fatou's Lemma do I use the limit of the $g_i(x)$?   Then swap back in for the $f_i$ and the inequality switches but where do I get STRICT inequality? by applying Fatou I can only get a less than or equal to. Am I going about this the right way? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You don't need Fatou's lemma here. These are very simple functions, you can just compute the integrals directly.

Comment: ok that is exactly what I thought, like first take lim inf then integrate and vis versa correct? a classmate mentioned to use Fatou.

Comment: Yes, the integrals are very simple. Anyway, Fatou's lemma doesn't give strict inequalities.

Comment: thanks a million! yes I kept running into that issue.

Comment: last question, when it says to state why this does not violate Fatou Lemma is it asking why Fatou's Lemma fails? OR how it doesn't go against Fatou's Lemma? is that because I can take $-f_i(x)$ or?

Comment: The question is why this example doesn't contradict Fatou's lemma. Well, this is because the functions are not non-negative.

Comment: cool thanks what I thought too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit of $f_i(x)$ is $0$ at every point: for any $x$ the inequality  $i\leq x\leq i+1$ fails after some stage. Hence RHS of the given inequality is $0$. Also $\int f_i(x)=-1$ by direct calculation. Hence LHS $=-1$. Since $-1 <0$ we are done.

Comment: quick question, by "fails after some stage" is that another way of saying that only for finitely many $I$ the inequality can hold true?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Yes, that is what it means.